# Java: Inject code before and after method call

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, code-injection

I'm risking this question knowing quite a few other questions [have been asked](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20annotations%20to%20inject%20code%20site:stackoverflow.com) that somehow touch the same issue. But they are either quite old, or very specific, or hard to follow, and the answers are also very specific and seem not applicable to my use case.

What I want to achieve is quite simple to describe, it is about injecting code before and after a method call in Java. Here is a simple example. I want something like this line of code:

```java
method(p1, @ANNOTATION(type=String) p2, p3);
```

to desugar to

```
Wrapper<String> w = new Wrapper<>(p2);
method(p1, w, p3);
p2 = w.get();
```

in the context of a larger block of statements, with a pre-defined `Wrapper` class. I have limited control over the build environment that is used to compile the code, so any solution should be realizable with Gradle plugins/dependencies.

What I've looked at so far (without having a deep understanding of any of them):

- *Java Annotations* : are never seriously considered in answers to similar questions, so I guess they are incapable of achieving that
- *Aspect frameworks* like AspectJ or Spring Aspects: are mentioned most often, but they only seem to be able to wrap entire methods, not specific invocations of them
- *Bytcode manipulation frameworks* like asm or cglib: seem generally capable of doing this, but are quite heavy-weight and require some plumbing, esp. on the build side, to achieve it

So, what could be a solution for this?

Comment: To my way of thinking, "code injection" is not the Java way.  In fact, it's something that Java works very hard to avoid.  Java is a *true compiler,* and I do not recommend trying to fool around with its bytecode.  I think that you should instead treat this as an "XY Problem."  Step back and reconsider what you're trying to achieve ... not the present idea that you have for how to achieve it.

Comment: Don't listen to this guy ^, your best bet is to use something like ASM, and insert your instructions whereever you want in a method, then recompile the classes and run your code. You can also look into the attach api, that doesn't handle injection but it gives you the classloader of the entire JVM you attach to

Comment: @MikeRobinson Thanks for the advice. I understand this going against the grain of Java. The underlying problem is that I need to manipulate variables of one method from another, and by all means haven't found a way to get around this. And while this is doable with wrapping and unwrapping values like in my example, the resulting code gets ugly fast, and I'm desperate for a more readable solution.

Comment: @Joe What would you use the classloader for?

Comment: Reflection, set/get fields, invoke methods, whatever you want, especially after you've recompiled. I also know theres an open source framework that handles injection I forgot what its called though I haven't used it in a while, but I was easily able to inject method calls/intructions right into class files without recompiling. It starts with J I know that lol, oh yes, I think javaassist

Comment: Transforming the code to get call-by-reference behavior into Java will become ugly as well, even if you manage the source code to look beautiful. As is any attempt to fight against the programming language you are using. Besides that, there’s a fundamental problem with the invoked method. Is the parameter type `String`, as the original code suggests, or is it `Wrapper<String>`, like the transformed code requires? Or do you intent to rewrite the entire method?

Comment: @Holger You're right, the formal parameter type would actually be `Wrapper<String>`. Which means the annotated code wouldn't type-check ... I may go down the road of just adding the wrapped parameter, instead of replacing the original one. This will be necessary for overloaded methods, to avoid the "have the same erasure" error when they differ in the type of the wrapped argument. - Basically, I have to re-write the caller and the callee for "call-by-reference" to work.

Comment: When you rewrite the callee, you have to adapt every caller, no just some callers, as you intended.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I have to adapt every caller. I just wanted to make clear that I need to modify the individual call site(s), and that the problem cannot be factored out to a central place like an aspect, at least AFAICS.

Comment: Regardless of whether aspect frameworks can change the signature, if I understand you correctly, you want to rewrite the method such, that it will write changes to the parameter variable into the introduced `Wrapper` parameter. I’m very sure that this is something, these framework do not support.

Comment: @Holger No, the unwrapping/wrapping within the callee would be done separately. And while this also adds boilerplate code to it, I'm more concerned about the readability of the call sites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206986/discussion-between-holger-and-thomash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ever so often on SO, answers are proposed in comments rather than in answers. So I'm picking from the comments above what appears to me as at least the most promising approach to pursue further:

Use a bytecode manipulation library like [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) or [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib).

Answer (score 1):

You could use aspectj to achieve what you want.
Lets say we have a compiled jar with a method similar to what you have described:
You want to intercept calls to `logStuff` method made from certain location(-s) in your application and change the logic to wrap the argument in `DummyContainer` object. Here is how your code might look like.

```
    @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface DummyAnnotation {
        Class type();
    }

    //that is your target method
    public static void logStuff(@DummyAnnotation(type = String.class) Object data) {
        if(data instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("String: " + data);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a string " + data);
        }
    }
```

Dummy container class:

```
    public static class DummyContainer {
        private String string;
        private Class clazz;

        public DummyContainer(String string, Class clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.string = string;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DummyContainer=[clazz: " + clazz + ", string: " + string + "]";
        }
    }
```

Aspect:

```
    @Aspect
    public class WrapperAspect {

        @Pointcut("call(* "
        /**method to intercept*/
        + "com.yourpackage.YourType.logStuff(Object)) && args(param) && "
        /**only calls made from within that location 
        * will be intercepted. Remove it to intercept 
        * calls from everywhere*/
        + "within(test.Runner)")
        public void logStuffPointcut(Object param) {}


    @Around("logStuffPointcut(param)")
    public void simpleWrap(Object param, ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        String calledMethodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        Class type =  jp.getSignature().getDeclaringType();
        Method method = type.getDeclaredMethod(calledMethodName, Object.class);
        DummyAnnotation annotation = method.getParameters()[0].getAnnotation(DummyAnnotation.class);
        DummyContainer wrapped = new DummyContainer((String) param, (Class)annotation.type());
        //code before method call
        jp.proceed(new Object[] {wrapped});
        //code after method call
    }
    }
```

Method within `test.Runner` class that calls `logStuff`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object instance = "thats a string";
        System.out.println("Obj type : " + instance.getClass());
        YourType.logStuff(instance);
        System.out.println("Obj type : " + instance.getClass());
    }
```

Output:

```
Obj type : class java.lang.String
Not a string DummyContainer=[clazz: class java.lang.String, string: thats a string]
Obj type : class java.lang.String
```

To build the project I use Maven. Here is how the build section of my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
    ...
    ...
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.13</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.13</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <Xajruntimetarget>1.8</Xajruntimetarget>
                        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                        <weaveDependencies>
                            <weaveDependency>
                                <groupId>your.jar.group.id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>artifactid</artifactId>
                            </weaveDependency>
                        </weaveDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not address some of my requirements:
- The DummyAnnotation is at the *formal parameter* of the logStuff method definition, not at the *actual argument* of the call site.
- Consequently, the `.clazz` attribute in instances of the DummyContainer class will always be String, and not vary with the call sites of the method.
- Also, it does not address generation of the pre- and post-code around the call sites which involve local variables. This cannot be solved in a separate method.
But thanks for making the effort.